# Is it possible that $2^n=3^n$ for some Dedekind-finite cardinal $n\gt0$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Is it possible that $2^n=3^n$ for some Dedekind-finite cardinal $n\gt0$?

I think the question speaks for itself, but let me try and satisfy the "quality standards" algorithm by padding it.

Yes, I realize that the equality requires a Dedekind-finite cardinal $n$ such that $2^n$ is Dedekind-infinite, and of course such cardinals exist if any infinite Dedekind-finite cardinals exist.

The reason I'm asking is, I want to know what condition I have to put on a (nonzero) cardinal $n$ to ensure that $2^n\lt3^n$, if I don't want to assume the Axiom of Choice. Do I have to say that $n$ is finite, or is it enough to say that $n$ is Dedekind-finite?

Comment: Great. No way I can get back to sleep now... :-(

Comment: (And I mean, it's not that I teach at 19 today, and have no chance of catching up on my sleep during the rest of the day because of the Pope's visit to Israel that forces me to get to the university much earlier than I have to... Wait, no, the other way around. You owe me four hours of sleep, buddy.)

Comment: It's unclear to me if that is equivalent to $n$ being dually Dedekind infinite. The Wikipedia gives two conditions it lists as equivalent, but it is unclear if it is "(a) and (b) together are equivalent to (c)" or "(a), (b), and (c) are all equivalent..."

Comment: Yeah, I jumped away and forgot that part of your question :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What Wikipedia page are you quoting from?

Comment: @AsafKaragila You mean it was a nontrivial question? How was I supposed to know that? Sorry about your lost sleep, but I don't think you should be on this site at all. How are you ever going to finish your dissertation if you spend all your time answering questions on Stack Exchange? The only questions you should be answering are your Professor's and the students you are paid to teach.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set It says being "dually Dedekind infinite" is equivalent to "there exists a surjective map from $A$ to a countably infinite set" and "the powerset of $A$ is Dedekind infinite." It's not clear if each of these are equivalent, or if both together are equivalent. If each is equivalent, you know that $n$ is dually dedekind infinite.

Comment: @bof: I rejected my advisor's suggestions for dissertations and came up with my own questions. So I can't quite do that. My students barely ask me questions this semester, so no worries there. And as for my dissertation? Don't worry about that. When the time has come to sit down and write the details, I will sit down and write the details. And answer a lot of questions on MSE while doing so. Until then, I use questions on MSE as a fertile ground for ideas for more problems that I can try and solve (see my M.Sc. thesis that started as an answer here).

Comment: Just to be clear, we're working in ZF set theory without the axiom of choice, right?

Comment: @user2357112 Right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible consistency result, and a suggestion for a reasonable assumption which work and another one which I conjecture to work as well. (And excuse me in advance for not using $n$ as an infinite cardinal!) $\newcommand{\fp}{\mathfrak p}$

Note that $4^\fp=2^{2\fp}$, so if we have that $2^\fp=2^{2\fp}$ then we have that $2^\fp=3^\fp$ as well. Consider Cohen's first model, with a Dedekind-finite set of reals. There we can find a Dedekind-finite set of reals, with cardinal $\fp$, such that $2^\omega=2^\fp$. Now we have that 
$$2^\fp=2^\omega=(2^\omega)^2=(2^\fp)^2=2^{2\fp}=4^\fp.$$

---

If you want a reasonable condition for $2^n<3^n$, as a start, here's one:

> $$\aleph_0\nleq 2^\fp\iff\aleph_0\nleq^*\fp$$
>   (Namely there is no surjection from $\fp$ onto $\omega$, which is equivalent to saying that $2^\fp$ is Dedekind-finite.)

If $2^\fp$ is Dedekind-finite, then either $3^\fp$ is Dedekind-finite and therefore strictly larger than $2^\fp$; or it is Dedekind-infinite, and therefore definition larger than $2^\fp$ (since we have an inclusion between $2^\fp$ and $3^\fp$, so they must be comparable).

My guess, however, is that the above condition is not optimal, but rather $\fp+1\nleq^*\fp$ is sufficient to prove that $2^\fp<3^\fp$.

Comment: Now if y'all excuse me, I still have two hours of sleep on my schedule, and I'm gonna try and use them.

Comment: Looks like you've answered my question! If $2^\fp=2^\omega$ then $2^\fp\le3^\fp\le4^\fp=2^{2\fp}=(2^\fp)^2=(2^\omega)^2=2^\omega=2^\fp$, so $2^\fp=3^\fp$, right?

Comment: Ugh!!!  Of course!!  And here I was, trying to get to $4$ from the other side of the exponent. I'll edit when I get out bed.

Comment: Do you know of any model where there is an infinite Dedekind-finite $\mathfrak p$ such that $2^{\mathfrak p}$ is Dedekind infinite, but $2^{\mathfrak p}<2^{\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak p)}$?

Comment: @Andres: Without checking anything, pick any model where the inequality occurs with any infinite Dedekind-finite set $X$ and consider $\fp$ as the cardinal of $X+\mathcal P(X)$. Or perhaps assume the existence of some infinite Dedekind-finite set $Y$ whose power set is incomparable with the power set of $X$, and $|Y|\geq^*\omega$; then take $\fp$ to be the cardinal of $X\cup Y$. That might work. (And why did I write `infinide` every time I wanted to write `infinite Dedekind-finite`??)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another example: Let $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak p)$ denote the size of the collection of all finite subsets of $X$, for any $X$ of size $\mathfrak p$. Now, if $\mathfrak p$ is infinite and $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak p)$ is Dedekind finite, we are done, because a nice theorem of Läuchli gives us that $(2^{\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak m)})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak m)}$ for any infinite $\mathfrak m$. (This is shown, for example, in Lemma 4.27 in Halbeisen's book.) But it is consistent that there is an infinite $\mathfrak p$ with $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak p)$ Dedekind finite.